# How can I access nested JSON object by given ID in C#, Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

My JSON is from url `http://192.168.1.50/vantaa/api/place` and it looks like this.
First question is how I can get the data from this JSON. I need to bind it in xaml list page.

```
{
         places: [
            {
              id: "243",
              title: "Abrams ja Husbacka",
              latitude: "60.25627906773524",
              longitude: "24.842572314971903",
              www: ""
            },
            {
              id: "149",
              title: "Alkupamaus",
              latitude: "60.27657927084334",
              longitude: "24.848795039886454",
              www: ""
            }
         ]
}
```

I need to using below JSON in new xaml page. In order to get below JSON, the url will look like this `http://192.168.1.50/vantaa/api/place/243`

For example, there is a list page which display data of above JSON. Once user clicked textblock of place id 243. It will navigate into new page then display binding JSON data of  place id 243 like below. (Image array is dynamic).

```
{
     id: "243",
     title: "test 9 image",
     description: "test 9 image",
     latitude: "60.80943244516333",
     longitude: "26.14554653906248",
     www: "",
     phone: "",
     email: "",
     contact_person: "",
     address: {
     street: "asdf",
     postal_code: "12345",
     post_office: "Vantaa"
},
     images: [
          {
          id: "100",
          filename: "50c95e58b30db1.JPG",
          path: "assets/images/"
          },
          {
          id: "101",
          filename: "50c95e59207ad2.jpg",
          path: "assets/images/"
          },
          {
          id: "102",
          filename: "50c95e599076f3.jpg",
          path: "assets/images/"
          }
     ]
}
```

Any suggestions on this problem?

ps: I'm new to WP and C# so please explain in simple.

Answer (score 4):

Create objects based on the JSON.  For example, a Place object would be:

```
public class Place
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string title {get; set; }
    public string latitude {get; set; }
    public string longitude {get; set; }
    public string www {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can convert the JSON into an object which a page can be bound to.  Use JSONConvert or JavaScriptSerializer

```
var somewhere = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Place>(json);
```

JSONConvert is from [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) and is a very mature Json library. You can also reference it using NuGET package manager.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you provide full code of JsonCovert ?

Comment: Check this blog post, it will  clear most of your doubts regarding the [JSON parsing](http://nkishorchandra.blogspot.in/2012/10/parsing-json-in-windows-phone.html)

Comment: Okay I got it now but how can I bind it into UI ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the JSON.NET library. You can get it through NuGet Package manager. (Right click your solution in the solution explorer and click manage NuGet Packages)

As Keifer said you can create separate classes to parse your JSON. However, if you do not want a class for each part of the JSON you can use `dynamic` instead of `var`. You also need to download the JSON, but I'm assuming you already did so and I won't go over that unless you need me to.

When you have the JSON downloaded you need to deserialize it. Like so:
We will assume you name your JSON to `jsonstring` after downloading it.

```
dynamic somewhere = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
```

to parse the JSON and get the list after it is deserialized you will use

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
JArray items = (JArray)root["Places"];
```